# The emergence of a loop in topology

Tags: networking, huawei-mobile-services

[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAAkU.png)

Hello, I have a topology (attached in the photo) For fault tolerance, I want to connect S6 and AC to each other, and then to the AP, before conducting, everything in the network works fine and everything pings, as soon as I conduct the right computers stop pinging addresses, for example 192.168.6.11, most likely because of a loop, I don't understand why a loop occurs, like all VLANs are configured correctly. I'm going to connect GE 0/0/3 On S6 and GE0/0/2 On AC, and then G0/0/4 On S6 and G0/0/2 On AP
Configuration:
S6
`

```
sysname S6
#
vlan batch 10 20 60 100
#
stp mode rstp
#
cluster enable
ntdp enable
ndp enable
#
drop illegal-mac alarm
#
diffserv domain default
#
drop-profile default
#
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
 authorization-scheme default
 accounting-scheme default
 domain default
 domain default_admin
 local-user admin password simple admin
 local-user admin service-type http
#
interface Vlanif1
#
interface Vlanif10
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 vrrp vrid 2 virtual-ip 192.168.1.11
 vrrp vrid 2 priority 120
 vrrp vrid 2 preempt-mode timer delay 20
 vrrp vrid 2 track interface GigabitEthernet0/0/5 reduced 30
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface Vlanif20
 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface Vlanif60
 ip address 192.168.6.2 255.255.255.0
 vrrp vrid 1 virtual-ip 192.168.6.11
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface Vlanif100
 ip address 192.168.100.2 255.255.255.0
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface MEth0/0/1
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 10 20 60
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/4
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk pvid vlan 20
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 10 20 60
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/5
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/6
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/7
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/8
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/9
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/10
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/11
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/12
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/13
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/14
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/15
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/16
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/17
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/18
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/19
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/20
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/21
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/22
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/23
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/24
#
interface NULL0
#
ospf 1
 area 0.0.0.0
#
user-interface con 0
user-interface vty 0 4
```

#`

S1:
`

```
sysname S1
#
vlan batch 10 20 60 100
#
stp mode rstp
stp instance 0 root primary
#
cluster enable
ntdp enable
ndp enable
#
drop illegal-mac alarm
#
diffserv domain default
#
drop-profile default
#
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
 authorization-scheme default
 accounting-scheme default
 domain default
 domain default_admin
 local-user admin password simple admin
 local-user admin service-type http
#
interface Vlanif1
#
interface Vlanif10
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 vrrp vrid 2 virtual-ip 192.168.1.11
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface Vlanif20
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface Vlanif60
 ip address 192.168.6.1 255.255.255.0
 vrrp vrid 1 virtual-ip 192.168.6.11
 vrrp vrid 1 priority 120
 vrrp vrid 1 preempt-mode timer delay 20
 vrrp vrid 1 track interface GigabitEthernet0/0/6 reduced 30
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface Vlanif100
 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
 ospf enable 1 area 0.0.0.0
#
interface MEth0/0/1
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 10 20 60
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/4
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk pvid vlan 20
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 10 20
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/5
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/6
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/7
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/8
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/9
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/10
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/11
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/12
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/13
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/14
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/15
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/16
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/17
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/18
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/19
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/20
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/21
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/22
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/23
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/24
#
interface NULL0
#
ospf 1
 area 0.0.0.0
#
user-interface con 0
user-interface vty 0 4
#`
```

S4:
`

```
sysname S4
#
vlan batch 10 20 60 100
#
cluster enable
ntdp enable
ndp enable
#
drop illegal-mac alarm
#
diffserv domain default
#
drop-profile default
#
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
 authorization-scheme default
 accounting-scheme default
 domain default
 domain default_admin
 local-user admin password simple admin
 local-user admin service-type http
#
interface Vlanif1
#
interface Vlanif100
 ip address 192.168.100.5 255.255.255.0
#
interface MEth0/0/1
#
interface Ethernet0/0/1
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface Ethernet0/0/2
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface Ethernet0/0/3
#
interface Ethernet0/0/4
#
interface Ethernet0/0/5
#
interface Ethernet0/0/6
#
interface Ethernet0/0/7
#
interface Ethernet0/0/8
#
interface Ethernet0/0/9
#
interface Ethernet0/0/10
#
interface Ethernet0/0/11
#
interface Ethernet0/0/12
#
interface Ethernet0/0/13
#
interface Ethernet0/0/14
#
interface Ethernet0/0/15
#
interface Ethernet0/0/16
#
interface Ethernet0/0/17
#
interface Ethernet0/0/18
#
interface Ethernet0/0/19
#
interface Ethernet0/0/20
#
interface Ethernet0/0/21
 port link-type access
 port default vlan 10
#
interface Ethernet0/0/22
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 port link-type access
 port default vlan 60
#
interface NULL0
#
user-interface con 0
user-interface vty 0 4
#
return`
```

S5:

```
`sysname S5
#
vlan batch 10 20 60 100
#
cluster enable
ntdp enable
ndp enable
#
drop illegal-mac alarm
#
diffserv domain default
#
drop-profile default
#
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
 authorization-scheme default
 accounting-scheme default
 domain default
 domain default_admin
 local-user admin password simple admin
 local-user admin service-type http
#
interface Vlanif1
#
interface Vlanif100
 ip address 192.168.100.6 255.255.255.0
#
interface MEth0/0/1
#
interface Ethernet0/0/1
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface Ethernet0/0/2
#
interface Ethernet0/0/3
#
interface Ethernet0/0/4
#
interface Ethernet0/0/5
#
interface Ethernet0/0/6
#
interface Ethernet0/0/7
#
interface Ethernet0/0/8
#
interface Ethernet0/0/9
#
interface Ethernet0/0/10
#
interface Ethernet0/0/11
#
interface Ethernet0/0/12
#
interface Ethernet0/0/13
#
interface Ethernet0/0/14
#
interface Ethernet0/0/15
#
interface Ethernet0/0/16
#
interface Ethernet0/0/17
#
interface Ethernet0/0/18
#
interface Ethernet0/0/19
#
interface Ethernet0/0/20
#
interface Ethernet0/0/21
#
interface Ethernet0/0/22
 port link-type access
 port default vlan 60
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 port link-type access
 port default vlan 10
#
interface NULL0
#
user-interface con 0
user-interface vty 0 4
#`
```

AC:
`

```
#
 sysname AC
#
 set memory-usage threshold 0
#
nat session icmp aging-time 600 
#
ssl renegotiation-rate 1 
#
vlan batch 10 20 60
#
authentication-profile name default_authen_profile
authentication-profile name dot1x_authen_profile
authentication-profile name mac_authen_profile
authentication-profile name portal_authen_profile
authentication-profile name macportal_authen_profile
#
dhcp enable
#
diffserv domain default
#
radius-server template default
#
pki realm default
 rsa local-key-pair default
 enrollment self-signed
#
ike proposal default
 encryption-algorithm aes-256 
 dh group14 
 authentication-algorithm sha2-256 
 authentication-method pre-share
 integrity-algorithm hmac-sha2-256 
 prf hmac-sha2-256 
#
free-rule-template name default_free_rule
#
portal-access-profile name portal_access_profile
#
ip pool dhcp
 gateway-list 192.168.2.1 
 network 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 
 option 43 sub-option 2 ip-address 192.168.2.200  
#
ip pool dhcp2
 gateway-list 192.168.1.11 
 network 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 
 excluded-ip-address 192.168.1.21 
 excluded-ip-address 192.168.1.31 
#
ip pool dhcp3
 gateway-list 192.168.6.11 
 network 192.168.6.0 mask 255.255.255.0 
 excluded-ip-address 192.168.6.21 
 excluded-ip-address 192.168.6.31 
#
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
 authentication-scheme radius
  authentication-mode radius
 authorization-scheme default
 accounting-scheme default
 domain default
  authentication-scheme radius
  radius-server default
 domain default_admin
  authentication-scheme default
 local-user admin password irreversible-cipher $1a$tm@YADf[cU$Fi8l+bo%j$!+g{+#Ti
M6Q(x{C-{*01Lq"qJ!{Fq9$
 local-user admin privilege level 15
 local-user admin service-type http
#
interface Vlanif10
 ip address 192.168.1.200 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select global
#
interface Vlanif20
 ip address 192.168.2.200 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select global
#
interface Vlanif60
 ip address 192.168.6.200 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select global
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 10 20 60
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 4094
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/4
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/5
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/6
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/7
 undo negotiation auto
 duplex half
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/8
 undo negotiation auto
 duplex half
#
interface NULL0
#
 snmp-agent local-engineid 800007DB03000000000000
 snmp-agent 
#
ssh server secure-algorithms cipher aes256_ctr aes128_ctr
ssh server key-exchange dh_group14_sha1
ssh client secure-algorithms cipher aes256_ctr aes128_ctr
ssh client secure-algorithms hmac sha2_256
ssh client key-exchange dh_group14_sha1
#
capwap source interface vlanif20
#
user-interface con 0
 authentication-mode password
user-interface vty 0 4
 protocol inbound all
user-interface vty 16 20
 protocol inbound all
#
wlan
 traffic-profile name default
 security-profile name emp
  security wpa-wpa2 psk pass-phrase %^%#tt0M~"=Zm2QNns;&WD,~:3,:SP!,g3v/-!OQM4)C
%^%# aes
 security-profile name default
 security-profile name default-wds
 security-profile name default-mesh
 ssid-profile name emp
  ssid Egor
 ssid-profile name default
 vap-profile name emp
  service-vlan vlan-id 10
  ssid-profile emp
  security-profile emp
 vap-profile name default
 wds-profile name default
 mesh-handover-profile name default
 mesh-profile name default
 regulatory-domain-profile name Egor
 regulatory-domain-profile name default
 air-scan-profile name default
 rrm-profile name default
 radio-2g-profile name default
 radio-5g-profile name default
 wids-spoof-profile name default
 wids-profile name default
 wireless-access-specification
 ap-system-profile name default
 port-link-profile name default
 wired-port-profile name default
 serial-profile name preset-enjoyor-toeap 
 ap-group name ap
  regulatory-domain-profile Egor
  radio 0
   vap-profile emp wlan 1
 ap-group name default
 ap-id 0 type-id 69 ap-mac 00e0-fcee-0f30 ap-sn 2102354483104E421E67
  ap-name area_1
  ap-group ap
 provision-ap
#
dot1x-access-profile name dot1x_access_profile
#
mac-access-profile name mac_access_profile
#`
```

I configured all interfaces on s6 as well as on s1, as well as all the corresponding interfaces on AC and AP, but it didn't help